# Magento 2 : After changing DocumentRoot Magento 2.1.16 is not installing

Tags: magento2, xampp

I have face some issue How can i resolve it ?

I have try to use multiple xampp for use multiple versions of php

> like php5.6, php7.0.*, php7.1.*, php7.2.*, php7.3.*

So i have install portable versions of xampp

- D:\xampp56
- D:\xampp70
- D:\xampp71
- D:\xampp72

I have change **DocumentRoot** inside

> httpd.conf from the location D:/xampp*/apache/conf

form

> D:/xampp*/htdocs

to

> E:/Projects

But i have facing some Error in Magento 2 installation

> '**http://127.0.0.1/mage231/setup/index.php/session/prolong**' return 'success:false'

Now how can i resolve it ?

Comment: you have to run them on a different port

Comment: @magefms how can i do in windows ?